# Android 1.6 setZOrderOnTop alternative

Tags: android

[setZOrderOnTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderOnTop%28boolean%29) was introduced with Android API level 5. Is this a convenience method for functionality that existed in the earlier API levels? If so, how would I go about creating the same effect on Android 1.6?

Some background info:
I am trying to get a GLSurfaceView with transparent pixels to render on top of the rest of my layout. So far I have not been succesful, the GLSurfaceView is displayed and renders properly, but pixels that are transparent show up completely black. My guess is that the default GLSurfaceView behaviour is the cause of my problem:

> The surface is Z ordered so that it is behind the window holding its SurfaceView; the SurfaceView punches a hole in its window to allow its surface to be displayed.

Comment: So lets say you simply have an image in your layout, you want your GLSurfaceView to draw transparently over your layout image? So as to maybe adjust the alpha and attain a "fade-in/fade-out" effect?

Comment: Your assumption is correct, I have an GLSurfaceView with transparent pixels, these pixels should show the image which is displayed "behind" the surface.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there isn't any way of changing the ZOrder of SurfaceView (in previous versions).

Because this requires access to the Window in which the SurfaceView is placed and there isn't any way to get reference of that window.

Comment: There is a function I can call which returns a window. If I have this reference to the Window, how would I go about changing the z-order of the SurfaceView? The function is documented here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getWindow%28%29

Comment: This method will return you the Activity window, not the window in which SurfaceView is placed.